# Using grep in shell file

Tags: regex, grep

I have a question about getting data in a file using a shell script. 
I want to search in some lines with more than one condition.

For example, if I have this file:

```
TX VIDEO ID 34 B 33 SIZE 672 SRC -1 DST 11 T 0.1 1
TX CBR ID 35 B 35 SIZE 10 SRC -1 DST 11 T 0.1 1
RX VOIP ID 0 B 0 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 3 D 0.001 0
RX VOIP ID 8 B 8 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 5 D 0.001 1
RX VOIP ID 20 B 20 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 8 D 0.001 1
RX VIDEO ID 9 B 9 SIZE 1490 SRC -1 DST 5 D 0.002 1
RX VIDEO ID 21 B 21 SIZE 1490 SRC -1 DST 8 D 0.002 1
TX INF_BUF ID 37 B 10 SIZE 776 SRC 1 DST 5 T 0.102 1
TX INF_BUF ID 39 B 22 SIZE 776 SRC 2 DST 8 T 0.102 1
```

In this file I have each of the `"RX VIDEO"` and `"TX VIDEO"` lines. The first condition I want to take data from is all the `"RX VIDEO"` within the `"DST 3 && DST 5"`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've edited your post trying to improve it's formatting. To clarify the last two sentences: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want lines with `RX VIDEO` that also contain `DST 3` or `DST 5`

```
$ grep 'RX VIDEO.*DST [35]' a.txt
RX VIDEO ID 9 B 9 SIZE 1490 SRC -1 DST 5 D 0.002 1
```

[**ref**](http://thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators)

Comment: i have one comment,maybe is not right all time ,for example if we have the "DST 10 " and "DST 11" and you want to take just the "DST 10" ? using 'RX VIDEO.*DST [3510]' will be take all ,i mean number 1o and 11,so do you have another solution ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For more than one condition you can pipe greps output to another grep.

If you want to search a file for lines with AAA and BBB you can do:

```
grep 'AAA' file | grep 'BBB'
```

Or you can search it with regular expressions with only one grep:

```
grep -e 'AAA.*BBB' -e 'BBB.*AAA' file
```

If an expressions after any of the `-e` options are matched, you will get a result. That means that it acts like *or*.

Both examples will find lines like this ones:

```
AAABBB
AAA BBB
BBB AAA
BBBAAA
AAA-BBB
AAA---BBB
AAAA BBB
xAAAAAAA BBB AAAAA
```

and so on.

**For your example it could be:**

```
grep 'RX VIDEO' file | grep -e 'DST 3' -e 'DST 5'
```

This will search for `RX VIDEO` together with `DST 3` or `DST 5`.

Comment: Why was this voted down? My answer tries to explain some grep basics and then addresses the inquirers problem.